# Sorting of already checked checkboxes in MUI Datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I wanted to already checked data is comes on the top of MUI data tables.
[Checkobx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POrGH.png)
Here you see in this image all the checked boxes are comes without sorting.

So I wanted to all checked rows are comes together and its comes in top of the data table.

Please help me into this case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, you are expectd to try something before asking. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is presented below as the function **SortCheckedAtTop**. For the solution to work, the list of rows needs to be represented as an array of objects (`rows`). The list of checked rows needs to be maintained using an array of row IDs (`selected`). Both `rows` and `selelcted` should be maintained using some approach to state management (e.g. Redux, React.useState, React.useReducer, etc).

General sorting can be handled using JavaScript's [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator). For example:

```
let collator = new Intl.Collator( 'en', { numeric: false, sensitivity: 'base' } );

function getSortedRows = ( rows ) => {
    rows.sort( ( a, b ) => {
        return collator.compare( a.value, b.value );
    } );
    return rows;
}
```

The function **SortCheckedAtTop** is based on the sort function found [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#githubs-picker). The function assumes that **rows** is a previously sorted list of objects. The objects might look something like this:

```
const rows = [
    {
        id: 0,
        value: 'something'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        value: 'something else'
    },

    ...

];
```

`selected` is the array of `id`s representing rows that are checked. If using `React.useState` to manage this array you might have a statement that looks like this:

```
// 'zero' is the ID of a row that is checked.
const [ selected, setSelected ] = React.useState( [ 0 ] );
```

### Solution

```
/**
 * Sort function.
 */
function SortCheckedAtTop( rows ) {
    let ids = rows.map( ( row ) => row.id );

    // Spread operator is used to avoid overwriting the original sort order of `rows`.
    // You might want to preserve the original sort order of `rows` to use it later.
    // in this function.
    let resorted = [ ...rows ].sort(
        ( a, b ) => {

            // Display the checked rows first.
            let ai = selected.indexOf( a.id ); // Index for row a.

            // If a.id is not in the selected list ai will be -1.
            // If -1, update ai by placing it at the end of the list of
            // selected rows. The end position is calculated using
            // ( selected.length ).
            // But we need to maintain the original order of unselected rows.
            // So, we add the position index from the original rows array:
            // ( ids.indexOf( a.id ) ).
            // If the selected list had 4 IDs, 'a' was not selected,
            // and a.id were in position 3 in the original list of rows
            // (zero-based array index = 2), ai would be 4 + 2 = 6.
            // This maintains the same order as the original list of rows.
            ai = ai === -1 ? selected.length + ids.indexOf( a.id ) : ai;

            // Update bi if needed.
            let bi = selected.indexOf(b); // Index for row b.
            bi = bi === -1 ? selected.length + ids.indexOf( b.id ) : bi;

            // Return the sort result.
            // negative value: ascending,
            // positive value: descending,
            // zero: undetermined (you can add more code to sort by another sort key)
            return ai - bi;
        }
    );

    return resorted;
}
```